# How to evaluate true if string contains text?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

In an Azure Data Factory pipelin, I need this expression to evaluate true:

`@bool(split(item().Name,'provider').Length>1)`

For context, item().Name is "provider_file.xlsx". (Thus I expected true)

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
Failed

{"code":"BadRequest","message":null,"target":"pipeline//runid/f16e4701-950f-4005-88c7-c4afc68b493f","details":null,"error":null}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Array.Length caused this error. You should use [length() function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#length) to get array's length. This is an expression equivalent to your expression: `@greater(length(split(item().name,'provider')),1)`.

The shortest expression to do this is:`@contains(item().name,'provider')`. [Contains function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#contains) can be used to check whether can find a substring in a String.

Comment: Thank you! This answers my question, educates me about the topic AND suggests a better way to do it. Bravo!